# laravel 6 redirect back to page after login using socialite package

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-6

laravel 6 redirect back to the previous page after login using socialite package. How can I achieve this with the following code?

```
     protected function redirectTo(){
       return url()->previous();
     }



  public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
   {
    try {
    $social_user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    $authuser = $this->findOrCreateUser($social_user,$provider);

    Auth::login($authuser,true);

    return redirect($this->redirectTo());
  } catch(\Exception $e){

    return redirect($this->redirectTo());
}


}
```

Comment: if you want redirect previous page you expecting want show login page ?

Comment: Whats about `return redirect()->back();` ???

Comment: @Hamelraj from where user comes to login page.

Comment: @TalhaF.getting this error - Method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::back does not exist.